# How to add / between spaces in a date

Tags: python

How can I take a string that returns it in a list with " / " between them, like dates.

for example

Taking 5,11,2013 and the output be 5/11/2013

Comment: Use a date formatter

Comment: Read the link in the duplicate provided. Ultimately, strictly speaking about the string manipulation you want to do, you want to use the string replace method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.replace()` ?

```
date = '11,12,2019'

print(date.replace(',', '-'))

>> 11-12-2019
```